# Are there any "hard lower bounds" to zero-knowledge proving space/time/commmunication complexity?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, algorithm-design, performance

There is a lot of "retail investor" hype implying a zk revolution in the future where we have circuits for common instruction sets and many software backends are zk-proven.

I'm wondering, are there any fundamental results (e.g. impossibility theorems, bounds) like, proving key must be x times the size of the unproven program (or even superlinear), running time must by y times the running time of the unproven program, etc (likewise for verifier code), that would compromise the viability of such a future?

Or is it, to our current knowledge, possible that we will one day engineer arbitrarily efficient zkVMs?

A subquestion here is whether it even makes sense to think about zk-proving complexity in terms of traditional complexity. I took a look at the big-O calculations in the [original zk-STARKS paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/046.pdf) and they seem a bit foreign from an algorithms/data structures POV.

Comment: The optimal prover complexity is $O(|C|)$ where $|C|$ is the size of the circuit. Regarding the proof size and verification time, people typically try to get $O(\log |C|)$ but I'm not sure if that's a lower bound.